Are there such things as ethical design patterns?
We should all probably be quite aware of dark patterns by now (whether you believe they exist or not is another thing), and I am curious as to whether there is such thing as the opposite of dark patterns (I assume they would be ethical in some way), but I have not seen anything labelled as ethical design patterns. Would they simply be considered good/decent/ethical design patterns, or something else?
I am looking for anything similar to the list of dark patterns, but for the opposite purpose.
UPDATE: Given that dark patterns are also commonly referred to as deceptive patterns these days, you can also use that term or definition if it makes more sense to you.

We know about Dieter Rams' 'Good Design' principles. https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/dieter-rams-10-timeless-commandments-for-good-design

We also know about Sustainable UX (https://sustainableuxnetwork.com/) which ethical design is a part of. But no ethical design patterns there as such.

Presumably part of the answer can be found in accessibility guidelines.

@Ren The 'Good Design' principles are certainly well-known, but as far as something that is as common as what we refer to as 'dark patterns', probably not as commonly practiced as we would like to see.

@locationunknown I am not aware of Sustainable UX, but looking at the 11 principles listed on their website, it does sound reasonably solid. However, it would be nice if they provided concrete examples or best practices to demonstrate them more clearly.

@jazZRo yes, accessibility guidelines often provide examples of best practices, and does feel like an attempt to encourage better design patterns. Usually the focus is a bit narrower as it is attempting to address gaps that still exist to make digital technology open and inclusive for all.

Nothing empirical, but I do make a distinction between 'Good' and 'Ethical'. Good design answers the necessity of both users as well as business. However, it's morality may be debatable. A good example I can think of is the Good-Better-Best pricing strategy where you place the actual product in between an inferior and a superior to make it's price look reasonable. This strategy is followed everywhere now where most manufacturers have a 'Lite' version and then a 'Pro' version. This is done to drive customers buy the one in the middle. Does it provide any less value to the user than it should? Probably not. But whether it is morally correct is debatable. So it is a good design but perhaps not completely ethical. Also, this is not a dark-pattern because the user has all the information to make a decision and they are not being forced in any way except probably the fear of social stigma in using the Lite- version product. People may be just too quick to judge based on looks rather than needs.

"Also, this is not a dark-pattern because [..]" - I do not agree. A "deceptive pattern" (as Michael Lai pointed out below, "dark" might not be clear) does not depend on hiding information - it's a nudge to support company goals at the expense of user goals. With the pricing strategy, I hold the opinion that it's especially a behavior of the company to advance their goal at the cost of user goals - and social pressure being created by a "Lite" label is a clever, but deceptive strategy for that.

@virtualnobi But it is not at the expense of user goals. The Lite- version was never up to the mark to begin with. We can ignore 'Price' as a measure and consider 'Value' as the measure. User does not lose any value.

Based on the question and the other responses, I believe there are ethical guidelines to measure how a website could be considered ethical. However, I don't think there are many good real-world examples to illustrate this concept.
First, let's consider the definition of a dark design pattern, as mentioned by the first responder: "A design that tricks a user into something they don't want." We can find many examples of dark patterns, especially in e-commerce.
Second, after reading numerous articles about Ethical Design, I found that most mention the same key features. An ethical website should be trustworthy, accessible, open, respectful of user privacy, transparent, and sustainable.
Finally, based on these points, I believe ethical design patterns are often applied only on paper to cover legal liabilities, rather than in practice. I'll provide three examples to demonstrate this point.
The first example is e-commerce. As mentioned earlier, we often see dark patterns used to promote sales—after all, that's the website's purpose. To define an ethical design pattern, we should look for components that build trust with the user. Instead, we often see alerts in the user's cart claiming that a certain number of people have the same item in their cart, which may only serve to rush the user into making a purchase. Another common tactic is showing messages that delivery is free if the user spends over a certain amount. An ethical approach would provide a clear comparison, showing the actual delivery cost and how much the user needs to spend to avoid it. An ethical solution might display a message like, "Pay the delivery charge of only $7.00, or spend $40.00 more for free delivery." This transparency can help build user trust.
Another example is in the field of data privacy. Often, privacy policies are made intentionally difficult to read, encouraging users to accept them without understanding how their data will be used. Wouldn't it be more ethical to clearly highlight what users are accepting? For instance: "By accepting this, you're allowing us to share your email with certain companies for marketing purposes."
The final example concerns environmental impact. Some airline companies offer carbon offset programs. I once joined a program from a Mexican airline that claimed to use ethanol fuels in their aircraft. However, this wasn't entirely true; the company had only a few aircraft that used ethanol, and it was never used on the routes I flew. Wouldn't it be more ethical to clearly communicate that the program applied to only a small portion of their fleet?


+1 I like the considered response, but I am curious as to why you haven't come across any actual examples. Even if it is just to make companies look good, surely it would make them look better if they could be a bit more specific about it?

I think that there are some examples on the NGO's websites that could be helpful to illustrate my response. There is a designer I follow named Soren Iverson that his designs could fall under the satirical category, and I would consider some of them blunt ethical.

'Blunt ethical' is an interesting term, I wonder if they are mutually exclusive or not.

I completely agree with your examples, but unfortunately we only agree on what deceptive patterns are (and we obviously have numerous cases) and your list shows we do not have (any?) examples of (and probably much less agreement about) "ethical" patterns.

Short answer: Conventional design patterns

A dark pattern is a trick that tries to coerce you into doing something you didn't intend to do. The opposite would be a clear and honest pattern that guides you honestly, without trying to trick or confuse you.
While you could call the opposite a good design pattern, it might be more accurate to refer to it as a conventional design pattern. Conventional patterns are widely accepted ways of designing websites and apps to be clear, user-friendly, and honest.
Good design patterns specifically focus on ethical and positive interactions. They are a subset of conventional design patterns, which cover a broader range of design patterns from clarity, honesty, familiarity, and ease of use.

I would argue that there are a lot of design patterns that are widely accepted, but not considered clear, user-friendly and honest, because that's how most of the companies that design services in e-commerce tend to operate. But your point about good design patterns being a subset of conventional patterns seem to make sense, because it takes added effort to get something from conventional to good, and even to something exceptional.

Not entirely earnest answer:

{your favorite list of patterns} \ {list of dark patterns}

A "Dark Pattern" is a design which tries to trick the user into doing something they don't want (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_pattern - is there a better definition?). Take away the trickery, and you have an ethical pattern - helping the user achieve their intended goal, assuming a "good" design aware of the goals.
The problem I see with this simple answer is that now there are loads of "ethical" patterns applied in the wrong contexts, which do not support the user's goals. So the ethical pattern might need to reference the user goals and cannot be defined as just being a "ethical pattern".
The other direction I could interpret your question to go is - are you looking for patterns which are especially "educative"? Like, making the users especially aware of their choices, or make them reflect on their own true goals. Here again, though, the user and their goals enter the picture, so you're left with the same issue: The pattern is "educative" only in relation to a target user group and their goals.
EDIT: I stumbled across this website https://superbloom.design/learning/blog/together-against-deceptive-design/ which discusses five strategies "to shift the tech ecosystem away from deceptive design and towards trusted design."

I think you've come close with the second direction. User goals can be unethical. An ethical pattern (if such a thing exists) directs the user to do the "right" thing. For example, in a comment system, a user wants to comment negatively on someone and get away with it by choosing the option to not show their name. An ethical pattern might force names to be shown to prevent people from posting negative comments too easily. Of course, this is just an example and not intended to be the most realistic.

Given that 'deceptive pattern' seems to be the preferred term now (I think because 'dark' is rather ambiguous and gray in its definition), perhaps you can look at the question using this definition (and I will also update the question).

@jazZRo I think you raise a good point about the balance between designer and user goals (if we just leave out the business and technical side of things), and I also think that this is a loop hole where some designers justify their actions. I asked this question a while ago but I don't know if there is an acceptable answer to this. However, there are many ethical design frameworks that try to address the various aspects and actors involved.
